# Router in React

Tags: reactjs, deployment, netlify

I have deployed a website created with `create-react-app` and used `netlify` for deployment. All went fine except that I have discovered that, `router` doesn't work properly. Direct link and refresh of the page ca I have to mention that I haven't created any backend for it. My router looks like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';
import ScrollToTop from './components/scroll-top';
import HomePage from './pages/homepage';
import AboutPage from './pages/aboutPage';
import ContactPage from './pages/contactPage';
import ServicesPage from './pages/servicesPage';
import PrivacyPolicy from './pages/privacy';


class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
        <ScrollToTop >
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path= {process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/"} component={HomePage} />
              <Route path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL +"/about"} component={AboutPage}  />
              <Route path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/contact"} component={ContactPage} />
              <Route path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/services"} component={ServicesPage} />
              <Route path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/privacy"} component={PrivacyPolicy} />
          </Switch>
        </ScrollToTop>
      </Router>
    );
}};


export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

## netlify deployments are for static sites

To get your app to work correctly you must generate a static site with tools like [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) or [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) (this Next.js link will take you to the static site generation)

The reason is that netlify will not run your router code on the server. It will only server static files.

Hope this give you some clarity.